# Send text message to Google voice number using php

Tags: php

I know you can send an SMS to a mobile phone using the recipients # and carrier suffix. Is it possible to send SMS to a Google Voice # using the same method?

If so, what is used for a carrier suffix? (5552125689@ ??? )

```
mail("5552125689@txt.att.net", "", "You have a new message", "test@mydomain.com");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, Google Voice does not support email to SMS.

You would most likely need to use an SMS gateway service like Twilio to be able to send to Google Voice.

[Here's how to send an SMS with PHP and Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/sms/sending-via-rest).

Comment: Signed up for Twilio - does exactly what I needed! Thanks for the tip!